# Diagonalize 2x2 block matrix where the blocks are diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Say we have a 2x2 block matrix:
\begin{equation} M = \begin{pmatrix} I & A \\ A & I\end{pmatrix}. \end{equation}

where A is a diagonal matrix (all diagonal entries are non-zero).
What would be the singular vectors and singular values of $M$?

Comment: By a simultaneous permutation of rows and columns, you are essentially asking what the singular vectors and singular values of $\pmatrix{1&a\\ a&1}$ are. I think you can calculate them by hand.

Comment: If the size of your matrix $I$ or $A$ is $n\times n$ then this is essentially equivalent to $n$ independent $2\times 2$ matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a solution, so I am answering my own question.

A singular vector matrix is

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} I & I \\ -I & I\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}.

Proof:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} I & I \\ -I & I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I & A \\ A & I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I & -I \\ I & I\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} I+A & 0 \\ 0 & I-A\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
which is a diagonal matrix.

The rows and columns may need to be permuted such that the diagonal terms of the diagonal matrix are ordered.